# Open DBeaver PostgreSQL connection via CLI on M1 Mac

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

Dear fellow DBeaver enthusiasts,

is it possible to open a DBeaver PostgreSQL connection via the CLI?

I installed DBeaver via `brew` (`brew install --cask dbeaver-community`) and put the `dbeaver` executable into the `PATH` (`export PATH="/Applications/DBeaver.app/Contents/MacOS:$PATH"`).

I am now trying to open a DBeaver PostgreSQL connection via the CLI. After reading the [CLI documentation](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Command-Line), I tried the following approaches:

- `dbeaver -con driver=postgresql|url=localhost:4444/giGgaPlyUPwc`
- `dbeaver -con driver=postgresql|host=localhost|port=4444|database=giGgaPlyUPwc|user=user|password=secret`

However, I always get the following warning in the console:

```
2023-06-14 14:25:04.811 - Initiate connection to PostgreSQL database [giGgaPlyUPwc@localhost] for Main <giGgaPlyUPwc>
2023-06-14 14:25:04.836 - {host}
java.net.UnknownHostException: {host}
```

Does anybody know why `dbeaver` tries to connect to the host `host` instead of `localhost`?
And does anybody know how to do this correctly?

Best regards!